# How to return and delete file?

Tags: java, java-io

I want to return file (read or load) from method and then remove this file.

```
public File method() {
    File f = loadFile();
    f.delete();
    return f;
}
```

But when I delete a file, I delete it from disk and then exists only descriptor to non-existing file on return statement. So what is the most effective way for it.

Comment: What do you mean by "return file"? Are you aware that `File` is really just a wrapper around a filename, which may not even exist? Perhaps you really want to return the *contents* of the file, as a byte array, a list of strings or something similar?

Comment: And on Unix systems, you could open the file and return an open handle of some variety, but Windows won't let you delete an open file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't keep the File handle of deleted file, rather you can keep the data in a byte array temporarily, delete the file and then return the byte array

```
public byte[] method() {
   File f =loadFile();
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
                byte[] data = new byte[fis.available()];
                fis.read(data);
                f.delete();
    return data;
}
```

// **Edit Aproach 2**

```
                FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(f);
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                int bytesRead = input.read(buf);
                while (bytesRead != -1) {
                    baos.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
                  bytesRead = input.read(buf);
                }
                baos.flush();
                byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
```

you can construct the file data from byte array

However, my suggestion is to use  IOUtils.toByteArray(InputStream input) from [Jakarta commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/download_io.cgi), why do you want re write when already in plate

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to return the file to the browser, this is how I did it :

```
File pdf = new File("file.pdf");
if (pdf.exists()) {
  try {
    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(pdf);
    httpServletResponse.setContentType("application/pdf");
    httpServletResponse.addHeader("content-disposition", "inline;filename=file.pdf");
    copy(inputStream, httpServletResponse.getOutputStream());
    inputStream.close();
    pdf.delete();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } 
}

private static int copy(InputStream input, OutputStream output) throws IOException {
  byte[] buffer = new byte[512];
  int count = 0;
  int n = 0;
  while (-1 != (n = input.read(buffer))) {
      output.write(buffer, 0, n);
      count += n;
  }
  return count;
}
```